# How to send dropdown selected value through ajax call to controller in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, controller, laravel-8

I'm new with laravel and I want to send the ***selected dropdown option value of product name through ajax data to the controller***

**For Example**: If I'm select 1st ***plastic product*** option value from a drop-down then in the controller from request object I want that selected product name

> as per my below code I'm getting null in the request object of the product name

Here is my **route:**

`Route::get('product', 'ProductController@index')->name('product');`

Here is my **controller:**

```
    public function index(Request $request)
        {
            if (isset($request->productName)) {
                $productName = $request->productName;
                dump($productName); // getting null
            } else {
                $productName = null;
            }
            return view('Product.product');
        }
```

Here is my an **ajax call:**

```
    function display(productName){
            productName = $('#product_filter').val(); // Here, I'm getting selected value of dropdown 
            $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "{{route('product')}}",
            type: "GET",
            data:{
                'productName' : productName // in header request I'm getting value [productName: plastic product] *
                },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(e){
                console.log(e,'error');
            }
        });
        }
```

> header request result
> [image: result]

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong,
ends with wanting to get help from helping hands please help me to get the selected value to the controller object

Comment: I believe you can't just do `{{ route('dashboard-product-data') }}` in javascript since it doesn't know how to parse it. Please check your response panel and see what do you get on the url.

Comment: @Ryoko, Thank you for replying 
as per your suggestion, I checked the response panel that is what I'm getting in URL `url: "http://localhost.product.com/dashboard/product-data"`
Could you please help me with this how can I parse it?

Comment: Okay, it seems like it's working. Try to change `isset` with `$request->has('productName')` and `dump` to `dd`. What do you get?

Comment: @ryoko I'm getting null while dd();

Comment: @Ryoko, I made almost all changes for this, and half of the evening passed to get this 
could you please help me with this?

Comment: Your code works just fine on my machine, would you please share your HTML & the script that calls the `display` function?

Comment: @ryoko 
In ready event I simply call this function on 
`$(document).ready(function() {
display(productName);
 }`

Comment: When I tried dd($request->all()); // first line in index method
I'm getting `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you got `null` because you are returning a full HTML to the Ajax request. In order to get the payload sent from the Ajax, you have to return a JSON response like this:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $productName = null;

    if (isset($request->productName)) {
        $productName = $request->productName;
    }

    return response()->json($productName);
}
```

That being said, I'm unable to reproduce the issue without seeing how do you call the method and where would you show the data to. And I assume you want to simply just do a `console.log(data)` like you did on the given snippet. In this case, the snippet above will work.

And if you want to keep the view to prevent error when you refresh the page, just add a new method for that specific call in your controller and send the request to that endpoint, like this:

`web.php`

```php
<?php

Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/productFilter', [ProductController::class, 'productFilter'])->name('dashboard-product-data');
```

`ProductController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function productFilter(Request $request)
    {
        $productName = null;

        if (isset($request->productName)) {
            $productName = $request->productName;
        }

        return response()->json($productName);
    }
}
```

`welcome.blade.php`

```html
<div>Product Name: <span id="product-name"></span></div>
<select id="product_filter" name="product_filter">
    <option value="plastic product">plastic product</option>
</select>

<button id="submit-button" type="button">Send data</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function display(productName){
        productName = $('#product_filter').val(); // Here, I'm getting selected value of dropdown 
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "{{route('dashboard-product-data')}}",
            type: "GET",
            data:{
                'productName' : productName // in header request I'm getting value [productName: plastic product] *
                },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                document.querySelector('#product-name').innerHTML = data
            },
            error:function(e){
                console.log(e,'error');
            }
        });
    }

    const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button')
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => display())
</script>
```